# Android using another XML list items combined with an array list

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, adapter, listadapter

So I have an array list full of data, for example:
    public static ArrayList topCaptions = new ArrayList();

I also have another XML file which has the look of the list item i would like, my question is...on my actual *ACTIVITY*, how do I inflate this file (r.layout.list_items) onto my listview(listView1) on my main xml.

I see people using adapters, but no clear explanationtion of how to use...when I extend into listView instead of Activity, I can't run my mainActivity.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to understand is the use of adapters. You have 3 things. Activity (user interface), Data (which you want to display on the user interface) and Adapter (the link between the Data source and the Activity which gets displayed to the user.

This is a very good tutorial on using adapters: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

In fact, there are lots of them. Google "Android ListView Adapter tutorial" and read through a couple and see different ways people use Custom Adapters to get a hang of their structure.